# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Application fails with a SQLite error when deploying the project to Azure Web Service but runs fine in local environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, azure, asp.net-core-2.0

The ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application fails when I deploy it to Azure App Service.

This is what is being used in the project.

- ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC Web Application
- Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise
- SQLite databases
- Code First Entity Framework
- Azure App Service

The web application works fine when I run it locally in Visual Studio. The problem results when I publish it to an Azure Web Service it cannot connect to the database. It states the following error when navigating to the deployed web application URL:

**SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Inventory'.**

I've tried several times to apply an **Update-Migration** or an **Add-Migration** to the database but it will still result in the table not found when deployed to the Azure server.

Here are my SQLite connections defined in the Startup.cs file.

```
     // Add Inventory DB
        services.AddDbContext<InventoryContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=Inventory.db"));

        // Add User DB
        services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=User.db"));

        // Add Purchase Order DB
        services.AddDbContext<PurchaseOrderContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=PurchaseOrder.db"));
```

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Yes, put the SQLite databases in the "AppData" folder in the .NET Solution directory and point your connection strings to that new location

Comment: @EmmanuelOgoma Were you able to resolve the problem you were having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the SQLite databases in the "AppData" folder in the .NET Solution directory and point your connection strings to that new location.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Derek solution, i modified my connection string on *appsettings.json* as i am using *Configuration.GetConnectionString* to fetch the connection string, and moved sqlite db to App_Data folder to wwwroot..

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyAppContext": "Data Source=./wwwroot/App_Data/myapp.db"
}
```